# What would keep setter methods from being created in sencha touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I have a simple controller that I'm starting to build in sencha touch 2:

```
  Ext.define('ScoreKeeper.controller.GameScores', {
         extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

         config: {
               refs: {
                     requestButton: 'button[name=RequestButton]',
                     responseArea: '#scoreResponse'
               },
               control: {
                     requestButton: {
                           tap: 'sendRequest'
                     }
               }
         },
         sendRequest: function (){
               Ext.Ajax.request({
                     url: 'message',
                     method: 'GET',
                     disableCaching: false,
                     scope: this,
                     callback: function(options, success, response) {
                           this.setResponse(response.responseText);
                     }
               });
         },
         setResponse: function (responseText){
               this.setResponseArea(responseText);
         }

  });
```

When I tap my requestButton the sendRequest method fires correctly but when it gets to the setResponse method, it fails on the this.setResponseArea step.

When I checked my browser dev tools, it looks like the getter methods for both of my refs get created, but neither of the setter methods do.

What would keep these methods from being created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `#responseArea` refers to an HTML element like a `<div>`. To attribute the response from your server to the HTML element, do this:

`this.getResponseArea.setHtml(responseText);`

instead of

`this.setResponseArea(responseText);`.

Don't forget `getResponseArea` gets you the HTML element with `#responseArea` as id. When you got it, you can do whatever you want with it; for example:

`this.getResponseArea.setValue(responseText);`

or

`this.getResponseArea.getValue();`.

That's why there is a get but no set.